# How to access and already existing (SNOWFLAKE) database with a flask application?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to flask and python in general. I just need help accessing an already existing snowflake database with flask. I just want to query the data. This is my code thus far and its not working:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from model import InputForm
from compute import preprocess
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABSE_URI'] = 'snowflake://<user_login_name>:<password>@<account_name>'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

engine = create_engine()
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)


engagements = db.Table('ENGAGEMENTS', db.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db.engine)
companies = db.Table('COMPANIES', db.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db.engine)

@app.route('/')
def index():
results = db.session.query(engagements).all()
for r in results:
    print(engagements)
return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What about it, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: I just can't access it. When I try to query the engagements table, it says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

There may be multiple things going on here.

First, if the error message you get is due to non-existent engagements table in the Snowflake db, it may be exactly that. Before you can execute queries, you need to bring your database at par with the models in your code. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database is a great source on how to set up your db. It teaches how to set up a normal sqlite database for migrations using Alembic. Luckily snowflake-sqlalchemy has alembic support: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy#alembic-support . You can use them to build and export migrations, and your db should be ready.

Second, there's two typos: one in your code, one in the documentation. Your code sets `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABSE_URI']` instead of `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`. And you also definitely need to mention your db and schema for snowflake as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204661/2928486. But the official documentation has incorrect uri.

```
'snowflake://<user_login_name>:<password>@<account_name>/<database_name>/<schema_name>?warehouse=<warehouse_name>?role=<role_name>'
```

Instead of the above, it should be the following:

```
'snowflake://<user_login_name>:<password>@<account_name>/<database_name>/<schema_name>?warehouse=<warehouse_name>&role=<role_name>'
```

Basically your connection params should be joined using `&` instead of `?`. I was able to set up my flask application using your code, and it is migrating and updating the snowflake db fine, so hopefully it works for other ddl/dql scenarios as well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a flask user, but it is possible you need to include the database and schema. I found a URL example below that includes snowflake account, database, schema, warehouse and role.

```
'snowflake://<user_login_name>:<password>@<account_name>/<database_name>/<schema_name>?warehouse=<warehouse_name>?role=<role_name>'
```